# Kentico13 - How to add customize links in CKEditor using Kenticos "Insert Link" dialog

Tags: kentico

We are using Kentico XP 13.0.44. Our content editors create news articles with rich text fields in built-in CKEditor v4.14.

Our editors ask for a feature to add buttons within the rich text: Basically, a link where they can define a label and a link target but that comes with predefined mark-up/CSS styles (predefined by developers).

I started to create a custom CKEditor plugin and, ideally, content editors could select the link target using Kentico's "Insert Link" dialog [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYmAV.png). This dialog is called and processed in CKEditor plugin "CMSPlugins".

Is it possible to somehow adapt/use this dialog in my own CKEditor plugin? Or what could be the best way to tackle this request?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest, lowest code, solution is to add a [custom style](https://docs.xperience.io/k11/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-the-editor/defining-styles-for-the-editor) to the style selector already in place. Let the user use the already built-in link creator/selector, then from the "Styles" dropdown, select the "button" style you want to apply to the `<a>` tag.